# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When I make a reservation request from the web page, it gives the following error. I wrote the web page codes on my computer. I debug. there is no problem and the site works perfectly on the local ISP. But when I upload the site codes to the hosting company, some parts of the site give an error. I check my codes on the computer again to see if there is an error and I build and debug again. there is no error. so the codes that give errors on the hosting company are working properly on my local computer and ISP. I don't know what to do. Here are the error codes I get from the hosting company.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm]'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm]'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm]'.] System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +175
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +107
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +49 System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +99 System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107 System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4() +198
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9850569
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4667.0

relevant page codes are below;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace VillaSite.Models
{
    public class ReservationForm
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ad Soyad")]
        [Required]
        public string Fullname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Telefon")]
        [Required]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "E-posta")]
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Villa Adı")]
        [Required]
        public string VillaName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rezervasyon Başlangıç Tarihi")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rezervasyon Bitiş Tarihi")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "İşlemi Tamamlandı")]
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

        public List<ReservationForm> ReservationForms { get; set; }
    }

}  


public ActionResult ReservationForm(string villaNameFilter)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        var reservations = db.ReservationForms.AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(villaNameFilter))
        {
            reservations = reservations.Where(r => r.VillaName.Contains(villaNameFilter));
        }

        return View(reservations.ToList<ReservationForm>());

    }
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ReservationForm(ReservationForm reservationform)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // Save the reservation data to the database
            using (var db = new DataContext())
            {
                db.ReservationForms.Add(reservationform);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            // Redirect to the success page
            return RedirectToAction("Success", "Home"); // Assumes "Success" is the name of the action to show the success view
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception (optional)
            // You can use a logging framework like Serilog, NLog, or log4net to log the exception.
            Console.WriteLine("Error retrieving reservations: " + ex.Message);
            // Show an error message to the user
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Rezervasyon Tarihlerini Kayıt Ederken Bir Hata Oluştu";
        }
    }

    // If the model state is invalid, return to the same view with validation errors
    //return View(reservationform);
    return View(new List<ReservationForm> { reservationform });

}  


@model IEnumerable<VillaSite.Models.ReservationForm>                                                                 <h2>Rezervasyon Talep Formu</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ReservationForm", "AdminPanel", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Villa Adı İle Listele")
        @Html.TextBox("villaNameFilter", Request.QueryString["villaNameFilter"], new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filtrele</button>
}


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fullname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VillaName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CheckInDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CheckOutDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsCompleted)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fullname)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VillaName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CheckInDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CheckOutDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsCompleted)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Güncelle", "ReservationsListEdit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Sil", "ReservationsListDelete", new { id=item.Id }) |*@

            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

My expectation is that the related codes work properly and the reservation request appears in the admin panel.